# Bug in review badge award algorithm?

Tags: bug, badges

It seems that two days ago, I was [awarded the "Steward" badge](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/badges/138/steward?userid=377345) for the "First Post" and "Close Votes" queues, although I received them in May and July of last year already. Might this be a bug in the algorithm?

**Update:**

Or is it a change of policy? The "tooltip stats box" in the review queues state "These badges can only be earned once", although I noticed that the help-center text (now?) says

> Complete at least 1,000 review tasks. This badge is awarded multiple times per review type. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

If it is indeed a policy change, it might be helpful to omit the "at least" from the sentence "Complete at least 1,000 review tasks.", as that may seem to contradict the "awarded multiple times per review queue" statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right, Steward can now be awarded multiple times: [Steward badge can now be awarded multiple times -- backfill details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360279/295232). This is rolled-out in parallel to [Visual design changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/295232) which will get rid of the wrong tooltip "These badges can only be earned once"; it is going to look like this:

[image]

For the moment, this is a bit confusing, but it's a [deliberate choice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1202029_360204).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I hadn't followed meta.SE for some time and obviously missed that. Perhaps we should keep the question for the moment just in case anyone else is confused (but I should probably delete it in 1-2 weeks to remove noise).